# How to decode bluetooth temperature sensor

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, decode, temperature

i want to get temperature from a bluetooth device and i'm stuck :

**There are some payloads, with bytes i've "cut":**

```
06 d7 0a 00fee107081e 08 2d 35 04  08:45 27,8
06 79 0c 00fee107081e 08 2e 35 04  08:46 31,9
06 13 0d 00fee107081e 08 2f 15 04  08:47 33,5
06 e7 0d 00fee107081e 08 31 1e 01  08h49 35,6
06 fc 0d 00fee107081e 08 32 1e 01  08h50 35,8
01|02|03|     04     |05|06|07|08
```

(The temperature is in Degres Celsius and i've got it from android device during bluetooth logging) but i want to get it from these payloads...

**So my analysis is the following :**
Byte 5 is HOUR.
Byte 6 is Minutes.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which characteristic you are reading, but I can guess that byte 02 and 03 contain the temperature information. Note that this is LSO...MSO, so you have to reverse the order of the bytes:

d7 0a -> 0x0ad7 = 2775  -->  27.8

79 0c -> 0x0c79 = 3193  -->  31.9

13 0d -> 0x0d13 = 3347  -->  33.5

e7 0d -> 0x0de7 = 3559  -->  35.6

fc 0d -> 0x0dfc = 3580  -->  35.8